# class variable that is modified by creation of instances

Tags: javascript, ruby

I'm curious how to implement something in javascript that I've done in ruby. Here's the ruby example:

```
class Person
  @@count = 0
  def initialize
    @@count += 1
  end
  def self.count
    @@count
  end
end
```

Each time a person initialized, the counter increases.

```
joe = Person.new
Person.count
=> 1
bob = Person.new
Person.count
=> 2
```

How would you I implement this in javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a property of a constructor or a factory method.

With a constructor:

```
function Person () {
   Person.count += 1;
}

Person.count = 0;

var bob = new Person();
```

With a factory method:

```
function person () {
   var p = {}
   person.count += 1;
   return p;
}

person.count = 0;

var bob = person();
```

With either of these you could also use an external variable instead of putting it on the function.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, javascript will have a `class` reference that will do the following as we are all used to in other languages, but today we use `functions` to declare "classes". I used the global `window` object to keep track of our `count` variable so that it would not be trapped in the scope of the class instance.

```
window.count = 0;
function Person () {
     window.count++;
}

var joe = new Person();

var bob = new Person();
```

Answer (score 0):

Static properties can easily be defined/updated in the constructor using the function name:

```
function Person () {
     (Person.count=Person.count||0)++;
}
```

now, Person.count should reflect the # of instances created by the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prototype property of every function object like this
//empty function,it will inherit a prototype property which stores an object

```
function Person(){}
```

Now,create

```
var p=new Person();
p.constructor.prototype.count=0;
var q=new Person();
q.constructor.prototype.count++;
```

This will increment the count of the same prototype object and this way you can keep track of new object's created.